# ¿Cómo insertar un gráfico de JFree chart en un panel con java?

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando en un programa que recopila datos y genera gráficos. He creado una clase que construye un gráfico basándose en estructuras de datos recopilados, pero tengo problemas a la hora de incorporar este en la interfaz gráfica del programa, ya que al cerrar la ventana de los gráficos, todo el programa se cierra.

¿Cómo logro que no se cierre todo el programa cuando cierro la ventana de la interfaz?

La clase que genera los gráficos luce así:

```
public class montoColones extends ApplicationFrame
{
Aduana aduana;

public montoColones( String applicationTitle , String chartTitle, Aduana aduana )
{
  super( applicationTitle ); 
  this.aduana = aduana;
  JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(
     chartTitle,           
     "Sucursales",            
     "Colones",            
     createDataset(),          
     PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,           
     true, true, false);

  ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel( barChart );        
  chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension( 560 , 367 ) );        
  setContentPane( chartPanel ); }
private CategoryDataset createDataset( ) {
   String nombre= null;
   final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset =  new DefaultCategoryDataset(); 

  for(NodoSucursal aux = aduana.primeraSucursal ;aux != null; aux aux.siguiente){  
      nombre = aux.sucursal.nombre;
      dataset.addValue(aux.sucursal.sumatoriaTotalColones, nombre, nombre);

  } return dataset; }}
```

Y el código que tengo en la interfaz luce así

```
private void statsColonesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{ 
   montoColones chart = new montoColones("Estadísticas", "Monto total en colones por Sucursal",aduana);
   chart.pack( );        
   RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chart );        
   chart.setVisible( true ); 
}
```

Comment: Asignando un setDefaultCloseOperation quizá? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)

Answer (score 0):

Asumo por tu código que quieres utilizar un barChart, yo lo hice así:

```
JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(
 chartTitle,           
 "Sucursales",            
 "Colones",            
 createDataset(),          
 PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,           
 true, true, false);

ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(barChart) {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(320, 240);
        }
};
cp.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);

add(cp); //este add funciona por que mi clase extiende a JPanel.
```

Este código lo he sacado de una pequeña API que desarrolle hace unos meses, puedes ver el ejemplo completo (o copiar todo el código si es lo que deseas) aquí: [BarChart.java](https://github.com/mayuso/Datuk/blob/master/src/main/java/chart/BarChart.java).

Simplemente crear una clase que extienda a JPanel, usar el `add(ChartPanel)` como hice yo, y despues colocar el JPanel directamente donde quieras.

Debería funcionar para lo que quieres hacer.

**Actualizo:**

He adaptado mi código para que funcione con el tuyo, espero no haber cometido errores.